# Targeting an element that was added after the DOM was ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm loading a map via script on my contact page. The map is loaded via following script in the header:

```
<!-- CSSMap SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cssmapsplugin.com/5/jquery.cssmap.min.js"></script>
```

Before the body tag is the script that initialize the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  // CSSMap;
  $("#map-europe").CSSMap({
    "size": 1450
  });
  // END OF THE CSSMap;

});
</script
```

This is the html code of the map:

```
<!-- CSSMap - Continents -->
<div id="map-continents">
 <ul class="continents">
  <li class="c1"><a href="#africa">Africa</a></li>
  <li class="c2"><a href="#asia">Asia</a></li>
  <li class="c3"><a href="#australia">Australia</a></li>
  <li class="c4"><a href="#europe">Europe</a></li>
  <li class="c5"><a href="#north-america">North America</a></li>
  <li class="c6"><a href="#south-america">South America</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<!-- END OF THE CSSMap - Continents -->
```

After the page is loaded the above html `li` elements contains `span` elements with class `.m`. It looks like this:

```
<li class="c1"><span class="m"><span class="s1"></span><a href="#africa" style="clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);">Africa</a><span class="bg"></span></li>
```

I would like to target these `.m` classes with javascript.

But when i wrote:

```
var testing = document.getElementsByClassName('m');
    console.log(testing);
```

I get:

```
HTMLCollection []
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that the `span` elements with class `.m` are loaded via javascript library of the map after the DOM is ready.

How can I target the class `.m` elements ?

Comment: You need to wait until after they're added to the DOM.  Does the library that loads them return any promise or callback you can use?

Comment: Thank you. I look in the documentation of the plugin and found some callbacks which helped me.